# Some notebook keyboard keys do not work in ubuntu

Tags: screen, media, keys

Installed ubuntu 13.04 on my Acer AS5733-6898, and worked well, but he does not recognize anything when I press the buttons to move music (with some player running) and also does nothing when I try to use the buttons that control the brightness of the screen, since that increase volume keys work well. What can it be? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Screen Brightness**

*From the Terminal:*

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. amend line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`
3. save and exit
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. exit and restart machine. (Works on Acer Aspire V3-571)

Comment: Ok I'm not with my laptop now, but I will test these commands later! Thanks for the tip!